# Adiabatic theorem in the regime of quantum optics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, perturbation-theory, interactions, adiabatic

I am wondering whether there is a version of adiabatic theorem in the regime of quantum optics. My understanding of quantum optics involves with the interaction between photon and atom. This interaction has always been almost instant. But the perturbation for adiabatic theorem needs to be as slow as possible. This is what confuses me.

Is there any adiabatic theorem for quantum optics at all?

Comment: Coherent laser light is not the same as a whole bunch of independent photons. The state of an atom can be changed adiabatically by laser light.

Comment: @PeterShor, thanks! I didn't know that. Just found this (http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0507268).

Comment: @PeterShor, what about correlated photons? Can we change the state of a pair of correlated photons (say, generated by SPDC) adiabatically?

Comment: I don't believe people know how to do that.

Comment: @PeterShor, Is that even possible? I think a prerequisite is to have single photon or biphoton system with ground and higher energy level. I am not sure how one can make such state. So I asked a separate question here (http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/72863/single-photon-or-biphoton-system-with-ground-and-higher-energy-level)